# Programa para avisar de una conexión en Linux (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

tengo un scipt con python que me avisa de cuando alguien se a conectado a mi sistema, el problema es que cuando lo ejecuto y me conecto con otro usuario me avisa, pero cuando me desconecto con el otro usuario mientras el programa se sigue ejecutando me sigue apareciendo que hay alguien conectado, este es mi script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import subprocess
import time

import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify
Notify.init("ssh2.py3")

a=subprocess.check_output("who|wc -l",shell=True)
b=int(a.decode("utf-8").strip())
print(b)
def funcion():



   if b>1:
      subprocess.run("zenity --info --text 'Alguien se a conectado'", shell=True)
      subprocess.run("sudo xterm -e home/sergio/Escritorio/prueba.sh",shell=True)      
  if b==2:
     su1=subprocess.check_output("who|tail -2",shell=True)
     su2=su1.decode("utf-8").strip()
     print("Se a conectado: ")
     print(su2)
     Notify.Notification.new("Alguien se a conectado", su2).show()

  if b==3:
     se1=subprocess.check_output("who|tail -3",shell=True)
     se2=se1.decode("utf-8").strip()
     print("Se a conectado: ")
     print(se2)
     Notify.Notification.new("Alguien se a conectado", se2).show()

  if b>=4:
     si1=subprocess.check_output("who",shell=True)
     si2=si1.decode("utf-8").strip()
     print("Se an conectado mas de 4 usuarios: ")
     print(si2)
     Notify.Notification.new("Alguien se a conectado", si2).show()



while True:
   funcion()
   time.sleep(5)
```

Quiero que no siga apareciendo que alguien se a conectado si solo estoy yo. Si podeís mejorar mi programa hacerlo y explicarmelo, me gustaría aprender. Gracias

Comment: Debes meter el `a=subprocess.check_output("who|wc -l",shell=True)
b=int(a.decode("utf-8").strip())` dentro de la función, si no, siempre tendrá el mismo valor.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que el sistema te notifique sobre nuevas conexiones de usuarios, de
una u otra forma tienes que guardar una lista de los actualmente conectados o de
otro modo no podrás saber cuales se han ido.

El siguiente código explota dicha idea guardando una lista de usuarios que
empieza vacía, y cada vez que se revisen los usuarios conectados se comparan
ambas listas para ver cuales se han añadido y cuales se han eliminado:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess
import time

import gi
from gi.repository import Notify
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')

Notify.init("ssh2.py3")

def notificar(mensaje, usuario):
    subprocess.run('zenity --info --text "' + mensaje + '"', shell=True)
    Notify.Notification.new(mensaje, usuario).show()
    print(mensaje, ': ', usuario, sep='')

usuarios_conectados = []
def checar_conectados():
    salida_who = subprocess.check_output("who", shell=True).decode('utf-8')
    print(salida_who)
    lineas_who = [linea.strip() for linea in salida_who.split('\n')]

    nuevos = []
    for usuario in lineas_who:
        if usuario and usuario not in usuarios_conectados:
            nuevos.append(usuario)
            notificar('Alguien se ha conectado', usuario)
            if len(usuarios_conectados) >= 4:
                print('Se han conectado más de 4 usuarios: ')
              subprocess.run("sudo xterm -e home/sergio/Escritorio/prueba.sh", shell=True)

    usuarios_conectados.extend(nuevos)

    desconectados = []
    for usuario in usuarios_conectados:
        print('Usuario es', usuario)
        if usuario not in lineas_who:
            notificar('Alguien se ha desconectado', usuario)
            desconectados.append(usuario)

    for desconectado in desconectados:
        usuarios_conectados.remove(desconectado)


while True:
    checar_conectados()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Dado que este código hace comparaciones con cadenas, es algo más ineficiente que
el anterior pero dudo que sea un problema dado que solo se ejecuta cada 5
segundos.

Por cierto, te preguntarás por qué hacer una lista de nuevos y de desconectados
para luego añadirlos o eliminarlos al final; Simplemente es buena práctica no
modificar una lista en el mismo ciclo que la está usando.